# Store images in HTML5 local Storage onClick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage, favorite

I am currently creating an app as a side project using jQuery Mobile & PhoneGap. This app will show multiple images and gives the user the opportunity to favorite an image that he/she likes. Once the user clicks on the button to favorite the image, that image will display on the favorites page (favorite.html). I am having trouble using local Storage to incorporate this task. Is it even possible to store and retrieve images to another page? Any help will be great. Below is a link to my jsfiddle if you need a visual.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2u2pkvvw/18/)

```
<!-- Page One -->
      <div data-role="page" id="one">
        <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Page 1</h1>
          </div>
            <div data-role="main">
                <img src="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg" style="width: 100px;"/>
                <br />
                <button id="favcat">Click Here to Favorite Cat Image!</button>
                <br />
                <br />
                <img src="http://www.dogslovewagtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Dog-Pictures.jpg" style="width: 100px;" />
                <br />
                <button id="favdog">Click Here to Favorite Dog Image!</button>

          </div>
</div>

          <!--Page Two -->
           <div data-role="page" id="two">
        <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Page 2: Stored and Retrieved Images Display On This Page Once Clicked</h1>
               </div>

            <div data-role="main">


          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: localStorage is really only used for key/value pair storing, not for binary data. However, you could convert the images into base64 and then store that in the localStorage, provided there is no issues with the length of that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must identify what image should be stored, you can see a custom attribute for image called data-name and other for button called data-image, both have the same content:

```
<!-- Page One -->
            <img data-name="catImage" src="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg" style="width: 100px;"/>
            <br />
            <button class="btn-add-image" data-image="catImage">Click Here to Favorite Cat Image!</button>
```

Now, when a user click on a image button, first you must get your image:

```
var myImageName = $(this).attr("data-image");
var myImage = $('img[data-name="' + myImageName + '"]');
```

After you should get the image base64 string

```
//Create a Canvas
var myCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

//Set width and height
myCanvas.width = myImage.width();
myCanvas.height = myImage.height();

//Draw imagem
var myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
myContext.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);

//And finally get canvas64 string
var base64 = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); // if it's a png uses image/png
```

And now save it on localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("image", base64);
```

And now restore on page two - page two HTML:

```
<!--Page Two -->
    <div data-role="page" id="two">
        <h1>Page 2: Stored and Retrieved Images Display On This Page Once Clicked</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" id="restoredImage">

    </div>
```

Page two JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = localStorage.getItem("image");
    $("#restoredImage").html(img); 
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for quick response and help Luiz! I tried entering the same info as illustrated above. When I inspect the element under console it says "canvas is not defined" Do you know why I would be getting this error?

Comment: Hey! No problem. I saw my mistake. I put "canvas.toDataUrl" instead of "myCanvas.toDataUrl". I saw other mistake too with var names. I suggest copy and paste again,

Comment: now I get an error saying "$ is not defined" in regards to this part of the code $(this).attr("data-image");

Comment: That's because your jquery.
I'll post an example without jquery, with vanilla js only.

Comment: So I have fixed the "$ is not defined" issue. Now it states the same issue as before. "canvas is not defined" I can add my updated code if need be.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code again? It was just an error because var names. Please search on your code if have some reference to "canvas" instead of "myCanvas"

Comment: Yes I copy and pasted now this error message appears. Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

Comment: i updated your jsfiddle. It's because you aren't getting a image. You're executing without an event. You must execute when you click on the button. And you must add a "crossOrigin" before request image. It's working.

Comment: This is perfect! Oh ok I'm proficient in HTML/CSS but I'm fairly new to JS & jQuery. Thanks so much Luiz!

Comment: No problem man! If it helped you is what matter! I would like just to ask you to put as "best answer" to help other people :)

Answer (score 0):

Other idea is use only vanilla JS

Page one - to save on localStorage:

```
var img = new Image,
canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
src = "http://example.com/image"; // insert image url here

img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";


canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
localStorage.setItem( "savedImageData", canvas.toDataURL("image/png") );
```

Page two - to recovery from localStorage:

```
localStorage.getItem("savedImageData")
```

JSBin example: https://jsbin.com/hewapewoxe/edit?html,js,console

Comment: ok I tried using this JS and I get no errors which is good lol but it doesn't do anything. Doesn't create the canvas, does nothing when I click on the button, etc. I added console.log(localStorage.getItem("savedImageData")); and it returns "data:,"

Comment: I put a jsbin example!