# Add to favorites/bookmark using HTML5 localStorage and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add 'add to favorites/bookmark' feature in one of my projects, but am totally blank regarding the same.

Basically, I'm using bootstrap glyphicons for user to select it if he wants add/remove from favorites. I did some research and found html5 localStorage concept suitable but can't really figure out its exact working for my project. It would be a great help if anyone here can guide me on it.

here's html:

```
<h1>test</h1>
<table class="'basic">

    <tr>
        <td><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty icon bkmark_icon"> </div></td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty icon bkmark_icon"> </div></td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty icon bkmark_icon"> </div></td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br><button class="btn">You have selected:</button>
```

since I don't really know the implementation of localStorage in jQuery, haven't added it, yet this is what js file has for now:

```
$(function() {

   $(document).on('click', '.bkmark_icon', function(){

       $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-star-empty glyphicon-star');
   // localStorage.setItem('display', $(this).is(':visible'));

   });

   $(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
       var bkmark_item = '<table><tr><td><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-star icon bkmark_icon"></div></td><td>*selected*</td></tr></table>';
       $(bkmark_item).insertAfter('h1');

   });

});
```

i did search over it and found this stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771737/store-images-in-html5-local-storage-onclick) appropriate.

what I need?

1. when user clicks on glyphicon-star-empty, it should toggle to glyphicon-star and the related item should be added to localStorage (i.e favorites).
2. when user clicks on 'You have selected:' button, it should remove current content which is in table and show only the favorited items(on the same page) with an option to un-favorite it.

here's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynpu5h7v/1/) the i'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a JavaScript object and serialize it to save it in localStorage. Use something like this -

```
var bookmarkedItems = [];
function ItemObject(name, content)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.content = content;
}

function addItem()
{
  bookmarkedItems.push(new ItemObject('Item1', 'Content1'));
}

function saveToLocalStorage(item)
{
  var ob = localStorage.get('KEY');
  if(ob)
  {
     bookmarkedItems = JSON.parse(ob);
  }
  bookmarkedItems.push(item);
  localStorage.set('KEY', JSON.stringify(bookmarkedItems);
}
```

OR

Refer below code -

```
   var storageService = function () {

        var STORAGE_KEY = "bookmarkitems";
        var bookmarkitems = {};

        var init = function () {
            bookmarkitems = sessionStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
            if (bookmarkitems) {
                bookmarkitems = JSON.parse(bookmarkitems);
            }
            else {
                bookmarkitems = {};
            }
        };

        var set = function (key, value) {
            bookmarkitems[key] = value;
            updateStorage();

        };

        var get = function (key) {
            return bookmarkitems[key];
        };

        var updateStorage = function () {
            sessionStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(bookmarkitems));
        };

        return {
            init: init,
            set: set,
            get: get,
            updateStorage: updateStorage
        };
    };
```

Comment: and how about fetching the data?

Comment: on page load, check if localStorage exists, if yes then fetch it and initialize the bookmarkedItems array.

Comment: can you please help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331061/cannot-replace-class-on-the-fly-from-localstorage-in-jquery-rss-feed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example on how to use local storage:

> ```
> // Store
> localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
> // Retrieve
> document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
> ```

You can reference [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for more examples.
Using it is pretty simple it works like any JS Object.

**EDIT:**
There are more extended examples on the functionality of local storage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: I've placed some more examples and im gonna take a look at your JSFiddle example