# How to store jQuery objects locally using localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, local-storage

I'm trying to build a to-do list app (beginner here), and have some difficulties in storing the values inputted so that I can store this locally, so once the page is reloaded, it's still saved. You input an item and it gets stored in task, and then it's checked if it's deleted or checked-off, and I think appended to an array, so I'm not sure if I should be iterating over this. Here is the code: (Thank you in advance!)

```
$(".txtb1").on("keyup", function (e) {
    console.log("sdfsdfsd");

    //13 means enter button
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && $(".txtb1").val() != "") {
        console.log("entered");


        var task = $("<div class='task'></div>").text($(".txtb1").val());
        var del = $("<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i>").click(function () {
            var p = $(this).parent();
            p.fadeOut(function () {
                p.remove();
            });
        });

        var check = $("<i class='fas fa-check'></i>").click(function () {
            var p = $(this).parent();

            p.fadeOut(function () {
                $("#task2.comp").append(p);
                /* No stupid appendChild */
                p.fadeIn();

            });
            $(this).remove();

        });

        task.append(del, check);
        $("#task1.notcomp").append(task);
        //to clear the input
        $(".txtb1").val("");

        //task needs to be set
        localStorage.setItem('task', task.text());
        var data = localStorage.getItem('task');
        localStorage.removeItem('$task');

        /* ------------------------ */
        //Other option: Store data
        localStorage.setItem('task1', JSON.stringify(task));

        //Get data
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('task1'));

        //Remove data
        localStorage.removeItem('task1');
    }
}
```

Comment: Simplest approach is probably use array of tasks and use `JSON.stringify()` when setting and `JSON.parse()` when retrieving

Comment: I’d recommend not spending too much time on jquery- it’s pretty outdated. Consider looking into React or Vue or something newer.

Comment: Please have a look to these documents [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to know how localstorage works. I find this one similar to yours, this can help you(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253177/add-to-favorites-bookmark-using-html5-localstorage-and-jquery).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you - I'm just getting familiar with jQuery - do you mean restructuring the code with React or Vue? Or can I keep it this way? Thanks for the link - will be sure to check this out! :)